# ADF - how to load multiple CSVs with different headings into one destination table

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have CSVs with different formats that come in through SFTP at different times. They need to be processed as they come in. Here's the problem: they have similar data but different column names. I want them to all land in the same destination table in a SQL Azure database. What would be the best design to solution this using a meta-driven approach? Can this be done with 1 pipeline?

Example:

**CVS 1 Format 1 (Headings)**

FirstName, LastName, Email, Address1

**CSV 2  Format 2 (Headings)**

LName, FName, EmailAddress

note both have different column heading names. The ordering is also different. One has an extra column. Both CSVs need to be imported into a SQL table with these columns:

**Destination Table**

FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress

It seems like the solution would need to use filename to map to a data flow for file specific mapping and put the result in a single dataset. Is that correct or is there a another way?

Comment: basically, you need to do a simple Join , can you please provide more info about the data that is similar? does the first row in the first csv matches the first row from the second csv?

Comment: updated the description above. the first row/column headings will be different.  the files basically come in through SFTP. they have different formats but i want them to be processed into the same SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to do a simple ***inner join***, which selects records that have matching values in both CSV's.

Here is a quick demo that i built:

**ADF**:

1. Create new pipeline -> add **"Data Flow"** activity
2. in Data Flows tab -> create new Data flow.
3. Load the csv files as a source in Data flow (look at attached picture below)
4. add a "**Join**" activity, join type: inner join and in condition, join the data based on FirstName and LastName.
5. add a "Select" activity and select only 3 columns as mentioned above
6. write to Sink (SQL DB or any DataSource that you choose)

**ADF Data Flow:**

[image]

**Join activity:**
[image]

**Select activity:**
[image]
Please read more about joins transformations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join

Comment: the files come in at different times. they need to processed immediately and funneled to the single destination table. would i basically need a separate data flow for each file type?

Comment: you have to do inner join to discard duplicated rows in your data. 
you can do the following: 
1. write files into a storage account (ADLS, Blob storage, SQL DB etc.) using Copy activity
2. After you copy the data, you can use activities mentioned above to further transform and analyze it, so the idea is to store both files in a storage account and then do the transformation on the data.